# prove that $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $T$ if and only if $\bar{\lambda}$ is eigenvalue for $T^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Suppose $\lambda\in K$ and $T\in L(V)$ where $V$ is finite dimensional  inner-product space over $K$ .Prove that prove that $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $T$  if and only if $\bar{\lambda}$ is eigenvalue for $T^*$

$<Tv,u> = <\lambda v,u> = \bar\lambda<v,u>=<v,\bar\lambda u>$

how to solve i am not geeing any idea

Answer (score 1):

The proof comes down to showing that if $T$ has an eigenvector, then so does $T^*$:

Suppose that $v$ is an eigenvector of a linear operator $T$ on a finite dimensional inner-product space $K$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then, for arbitrary vector $x \in K$,

$0=<0,x>=<(T-\lambda I)(v),x)>=<v,(T-\lambda I)^*, (x))> = <v,(T^* -\bar{\lambda} I),(x)>$

From here, notice that $v$ is orthogonal to the range of $(T^* -\bar{\lambda} I)$.

What can you say from here about the kernel?

Comment: ...not understand

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: ..other part if $\bar{\lambda}$ is eigenvalue for $\lambda$ is eigenvaluefor t

Answer (score 1):

$$\langle\,T^*u, v\,\rangle
= \overline{\langle\,Tv, u\,\rangle}
= \overline{\langle\,\lambda v, u\,\rangle}
= \overline{\bar{\lambda}\langle\,v, u\,\rangle}
= \lambda \langle\,u,v\,\rangle
= \langle\, \bar{\lambda}u,v\,\rangle
$$
Going the other way:
$$\langle\,Tv, u\,\rangle
= \overline{\langle\,T^*u, v\,\rangle}
= \overline{\langle\,\bar{\lambda} u, v\,\rangle}
= \overline{\lambda\langle\,u, v\,\rangle}
= \bar{\lambda} \langle\,v,u\,\rangle
= \langle\, \lambda v,u \,\rangle
$$

Comment: @adfriedman...i have faced problem with other part

Comment: You just have to reverse all the steps to get the other direction, the philosophy is the same.

Comment: Hopefully my addition makes it clear.

Comment: Are you sure this answer is correct? I think it is incomplete, because we need $v$ to be an eigenvector.

Comment: @DaviBarreira sure, as to match the OPs notation, I am assuming $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to $\lambda$ in the first direction. In the other direction we are assuming $\bar{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue corresponding to eigenvector $u$ of $T^*$.

Comment: But how does this implies their equality? I mean, if $u$ is an eigenvector o $T^*$, then you have $<\bar\lambda u, v> = <\lambda ', v>$. But how do you conclude the equality between $\bar\lambda$ and $\lambda$'?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I don't see the implication, since $u$ and $v$ could be orthogonal.

Comment: I assume you mean to ask why $\langle \bar{\lambda} u, v\rangle = \langle \lambda' u, v\rangle$ implies $\bar{\lambda}=\lambda'$?

It's because $$0 = \langle \bar{\lambda} u, v\rangle - \langle \lambda' u, v\rangle
= \langle (\bar{\lambda}-\lambda') u, v\rangle
$$

Now note that $v$ was arbitrary (which includes cases of $v$ orthogonal and cases of $v$ parallel to $u$) so we could choose $v=(\bar{\lambda}-\lambda') u$ and then apply positive definiteness of inner product to conclude either $\bar{\lambda}-\lambda'=0$ or $u=0$. $u=0$ is not an eigenvector, so $\bar{\lambda} = \lambda'$.

Comment: It's really just the theorem that $$\langle u_1,v\rangle = \langle u_2,v\rangle\;\text{for all $v\in V$} \implies u_1=u_2.$$

Comment: But $v$ and $u$ are not arbitrary, they are eigenvectors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109501/discussion-between-davi-barreira-and-adfriedman).